# org.w3c.dom.Document to XML string using Groovy

Tags: xml, dom, groovy

I have an org.w3c.dom.Document instance which I need to convert to an XML string. I know how to do this in Java (using javax.xml.transform facilities), but I wondered whether there is a more "groovy" way of doing this?

I've tried using a the DomToGroovy class, which successfully create a groovy script version of the DOM document. But I'm not sure how I would use this to generate an XML string. I might be barking up the wrong tree...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I wondered whether there is a more "groovy" way of doing this?

There sure is: class [groovy.xml.XmlUtil](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/index.html?groovy/xml/XmlUtil.html)

I'm not sure what was the version of Groovy when this class was added, but I guess it was an early version.

**Edit**: class groovy.xml.XmlUtil [exists since version 1.6.0](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/main/groovy/xml/XmlUtil.java); in version 1.5.x, it was named [groovy.xml.dom.DOMUtil](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/groovy/tags/GROOVY_1_5_1/groovy/src/main/groovy/xml/dom/DOMUtil.java). In either version, this class doesn't do anything too groovy; if you look at [its source](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/~raw,r=14058/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/main/groovy/xml/XmlUtil.java), you'll see it's just a wrapper around `java.xml.transform`. However, I really appreciate that the Groovy GDK provides a simple way to do such a common operation (writing xml to a string), while the Java JDK fails to.

Example:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def fileName = 'build.xml'

def builder     = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
def inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName)
def doc         = builder.parse(inputStream)

println XmlUtil.serialize(doc.documentElement)
```

Always look at the [Groovy API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/) and the [Groovy extensions to the JDK](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/) before rolling your own solution (a lesson I learned the hard way)

Comment: I think it was added in Groovy 1.6. It is not in the Groovy 1.5 that comes with NetBeans 6.5

Answer (score 2):

It's very groovy now

```
> def doc = groovy.xml.DOMBuilder.newInstance().parseText("<foo count='42'><bar/><foo>")
> doc.documentElement as String
<foo count="42">
  <bar/>
</foo>
```